# Get archives as array

Tags: archives, array, categories, wp-get-archives

I'm looking for a way to get the values returned from `wp_get_archives` as an array, similar to `get_categories`. I need to do this to modify the post counters to use `- [#]` instead of `(#)`. See my current code below:

**My code for categories, which displays as desired:**

```
$cats = get_categories();
if ($cats) {
    echo "<section class='widget'>";
    echo "<header><h4>Categories</h4></header>";
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($cats as $cat) {
        echo "<li><a href='" . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . "'>" . $cat->name . "</a> - [" . $cat->count . "]</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
    echo "</section><!--/.widget-->";
}
```

**My code for archvies, which *does not* display as desired:**

```
$archives = wp_get_archives(array(
    "echo"            => 0,
    "show_post_count" => true,
));
if ($archives) {
    echo "<section class='widget'>";
    echo "<header><h4>Archives</h4></header>";
    echo "<ul class='cats'>" . $archives . "</ul>";
    echo "</section><!--/.widget-->";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [`wp_get_archives()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1321) you will notice that [the link is generated](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.1.1/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1413) by [`get_archives_link()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_archives_link). That function supplies a filter that will allow you to replace the parens.

This is fairly crude but does work.

```
function archive_link_wpse_183665($link) {
  $pat = '|\(([^)])\)</li>|';
  //   preg_match($pat,$link,$matches);
  //   var_dump($matches);

  $link = preg_replace($pat,'[$1]',$link);
  return $link;
}
add_filter( 'get_archives_link', 'archive_link_wpse_183665' );
```